# I am having overflow issue in responsive view under 300 px

Tags: css, responsive-design, response

I am having an issue in the mobile version of the webiste and I wasn't able to find the cause but I think there is a shortage of overflows in either html tag or body tag. I tried a lot of things none of which worked. The website flows out of screen or some areas are not covered at all under 300 px. Which CSS code should I remove or add?

The address of the website I am having trouble with: https://wisekitten.com/can-cats-eat-mayo/

IMG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwOEP.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with your margins on the right, so I'd look at that. Also just a general rule of thumb, you should use percentages in CSS instead of pixels. Your left margins are fine. [image: Mobile View]